# SIFT in matlab using vl_sift function

Tags: matlab, sift

I am using vl_sift(from vl_feat site)function for finding SIFT descriptor, which is giving me descriptor of size 128*1 for one image and 128*2 for the second. I got the reason behind 128 but I am not getting why the columns keep changing(sometimes 1 and sometimes 2),it has to be same right?  Can anyone explain me what does those columns represents?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features are extracted from the key points. In SIFT case they are blob like structures. In other words the vl_sift function looks for the key point and extracts a 128 dimensional descriptor from EACH of the key points.

You have various dimensions (128*1 or 128*2 etc...) because in one image vl_sift finds one key point in the other one it finds 2 key points. That is why you have various dimensions.

Comment: So sir, how to restrict those key points then, if I want to get same dimensions? Can we set key points (or their coordinates) in that case, in a particular image? because there is no provision to force 'vl_sift' function to use manually given key points. I have created key points manually here. please tell me sir. And Thank you sir for your reply.

Comment: @Nachiket Yes you can define the points where you will extract the features by using dense sift (vl_dsift). See the link: [http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_dsift.html] you can also use the vl_phow ([http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_phow.html]). They simply extract the features from a regularly spread points.

Comment: Ohhk thank you sir. Let me try them. And thank you for quickkkkk reply. :)

Comment: Sir I went through the description of vl_dsift but couldn't get the concept of how to give 'keypoints' coordinates to that function. I tried vl_dsift(,,'bounds',[x1,y1,x2,y2]) where I can define smaller area over which only it will find the descriptors. But its not working its giving me empty matrix for features as well as descriptors. Will you please show me how can I use only specific 'keypoints' to get the descriptors? Thank you

Comment: What you can do is to look at the FRAMES returned by vl_dsift [FRAMES,DESCRS] = VL_DSIFT. FRAMES stores the **x and y coordinates** of the center of the box where the sift features are extracted. So you can define the keypoint coordinates by playing with **step** and **size** options. you extract features by moving the window by step pixels. You can see the following link for detailed explanation. [link[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289003/vl-dsift-trying-to-get-a-feature-vector-at-every-pixel/33312863#33312863)

Comment: No actually sir what I am saying is I have key points with me.( I am considering corner points as my keypoints.) so I have x,y coordinates of them. Now I want t find decsriptors corresponding to those particular key points only.  Can I able to find that using vl_dsift?or as you have sugessted vl_phow?

Comment: @Nachiket You can design the size and step variables in such a way that they overlap with the position of your key points... You can also ask the same question to https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat

Answer (score 0):

SIFT extract an arbitrary amount of descriptors, each of size 128. The amount of descriptors extracted will not be a fixed number, as it depends on how many points are "strong enough" to be a good descriptor. Each of the descriptor has 128 "features" in the SIFT algorithm, other (such as SURF, 64 features) will have different.

In your case, you are getting a single feature in the first image, 2 in the seccond. That is a *very very* few amount of features, maybe your images are too small?

Comment: Yes sir thats correct my images are of size 20*20 only. So according to you I cant control the size of the descriptors right? More the size more is the feature that are extracted? And If I want to keep the size same can this be possible? Thank you